# На выводятся ошибки в readyRead

Tags: c++, qt, bat, qwidget

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
    QString program = "PyModuleInstaller.bat";
    QProcess *Process = new QProcess(this);
    Process->start(program);
    connect(Process, &QProcess::readyReadStandardOutput, [=] {
        ui->plainTextEdit->appendPlainText(Process->readAll());
    });
}
```

Этот код должен считывать данные, выводимые bat файлом и отправлять их plainText. Вот bat:

```
chcp 1251
cd /d "C:\Users\Пользователь\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts"
pip install adsabs
```

Выполнение bat файла вызывает ошибку, но она не выводится в plainText. [image: ошибка в консоли]

Если вместо readAll написать readError - не компилируется (я не знаю как её использовать), а если `readyReadStandardOutput` заменить (или добавить) `readyReadStandardError` ошибки всё равно не выводятся, только пустых строчек больше. Подскажите, как это исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

замените `Process->readAll()` на `Process->readAllStandardError()` a `readyReadStandardOutput` на `readyReadStandardError`

Comment: Спасибо, а можно как то узнать произошла ли ошибка, и если произошла - показать окно plainText?

Comment: @Стас https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#exitStatus

Comment: насколько я понимаю, сигнал readyReadStandardOutput должен вызваться только если в него было что-то записано. Соответственно, если в канале ничего нет - он и не будет вызван, а если есть - то в эдитор будут добавлены соответствующие строки